# Firefox CSS position unpredictable behaviour

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, position

I have same HTML/CSS code working different in Chrome or Safari versus Firefox.

But Firefox also works sometimes.

For instance, if you resize the codepen window, inspect or make a change to the label of the input in Firefox, it behaves correct and then incorrect again.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/jmaguirrei/pen/gxrrrP)

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

div, input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.my-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.label-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
}

.input-wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.my-input {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 44px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="my-field">
    <div class="label-wrap">
      <div class="label">
        <span>Change this labe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100%" height="100%">
          <g>
            <path d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="my-input">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Or resize codepen layout" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Inside Stack Overflow Chrome vs Firefox comparison

[image: Inside Stack Overflow Chrome vs Firefox comparison]

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

In Safari:

[image: Safari]

Any tip on how manage this in a safe way is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? I can't replicate the issue in v54.0.1.

Comment: I am on exact same version (64-bit) on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work on every browser, you can remove

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

on the `icon-wrap` div and add

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

So you will vertically align the icon only with the absolute position.

This solution should work on Chrome, Safari & Firefox :)

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

div, input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.my-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.label-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
  flex: 1;
}

.input-wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-wrap {
  /* Remove this */
  /* display: flex; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  /* Add this */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.my-input {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 44px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="my-field">
    <div class="label-wrap">
      <div class="label">
        <span>Change this labe</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100%" height="100%">
          <g>
            <path d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="my-input">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Or resize codepen layout" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work on Firefox, but it breaks Safari (the icon now appears below the input), maybe needs another rule?

Comment: Hmm i see, your code seems pretty big for what you need to do, i will try to help you. You just need an input with the icon on the left and input on the right ?

Comment: I actually copied the html generated from a larger React Component, that also has a tooltip on the right. I think I can figure it out with a simpler example working in the 3 browsers, and then test it with React.

Comment: I have edited my answer now it should work on every browser. So I didn't update the code of the react component, tell me if this work for you :) @JoséManuelAguirre

Comment: Thanks Victor, that solves this case. But I wonder if there a general tip when working with alignment with flexbox on this browsers, because transforming the elements looks "hacky"... Let me know if you know where can I find more info about this. Many thanks for your help.